# Ionic 4 writing json file blocked by CORS

Tags: file, ionic4

I'm trying to write a JSON file with my ionic 4 app

I tried the following path:
applicationStorageDirectory
cacheDirectory
dataDirectory
and it giving me the same error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///URL/my_file.json' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https

Here is my code for writing a file:

```
this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory + "json_data", 'test.json', JSON.stringify(cars_data), {replace: true});
```

I want to save the JSON data in the JSON file.

Comment: can you add the error message ?

Comment: Yes. The error is Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///URL/my_file.json' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https